Can't select an aura component in autolaunched flow
I have created an autolaunched flow to make a field update and later I had to create an aura because when the flow is called via button the field is not updated on the record page (it is update in the backend). I have seen that this is a common issue and that I needed the aura.
After deploying the aura I have tried searching for it in the action block in the flow but I can't find it.
Here is the code:
refreshView.cmp
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,lightning:availableForFlowActions,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
    <!-- no markup needed -->
</aura:component>

refreshViewController.js
({
    invoke : function(component, e, helper) {
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();

    }
})


Am I missing something?
Thanks for your help.

LWC components will be available as screen actions in Summer '24. Unclear whether that'll solve your issue but FYI.

This question is similar to: Is there a way to refresh a record after an autolaunched flow is executed?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As per the Documentation, You can use the Aura Component as flow action in screen flow not an other type of flow.

Lightning components require a browser context to run, so flow action
components are supported only in screen flows.

